# Remove certain elements in one list based on condition from another list

Tags: java, lambda, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I'm fairly new to Java 8. I have a requirement to subtract/remove POJOs in one list based on certain criteria (from another list) and show it on UI.

1. Iterate one list and search for condition
2. Remove the object
3. Send the original list to UI

Children.java

```java
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String school;
private String personId;
// Setters and getters.
```

Person.java

```java
private String personId;
private String fullName;
private String address;
// Setters and Getters.
```

Main code

```java
// populated by other methods.
List<Person> personList;

//Connect to DB and get ChildrenList
List<Children> childrenList = criteria.list();

for(Children child : childrenList) {
   personList.removeIf(person -> child.getPersonId().equals(person.getPersonId()));
}
```

Is there any better way to handle the for-loop?

Comment: it's simple to read, it's using `removeIf` (exactly what it was intended for), why would you want to change it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The code that you have right now works perfectly, but is also `O(n * m)` since `removeIf` iterates through the `List` for every `Children`.  One way to improve would be to store every child's `personId` in a `Set<String>` and remove every `Person` from the `List<Person>` if their `personId` is contained in the `Set`:

```
Set<String> childIds = childrenList.stream()
                                   .map(Children::getPersonId)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toSet());

personList.removeIf(person -> childIds.contains(person.getPersonId()));
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This code will run faster.

Comment: Any change in speed will be negligible for small data sets, but you're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Just another way of doing same but without mutating the original list:

```
 Set<String> childIds = childrenList.stream()
                .map(Children::getPersonId)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        personList = personList.stream().filter(person ->
                !childIds.contains(person.getPersonId())
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It should have a bit of increased space complexity but you could take advantage of `parallelStream` here.

Comment: I like this one better as in my case I just need to remove a single string instead of list of strings. hence all I just needed is this like of code  personList = personList.stream().filter(person ->
                !childIds.contains("String to Remove")
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());........ thanks

Answer (score 3):

Adding this here in case someone needs it;

If what you want to do is not checking the contents, but an equalization, you can do the same code as follows;

```
listName.removeIf(listItem -> listItem.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Name") ||
                    listItem.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Other Name"));
```

This code is versatile and saved me lines of code and the need for a forEach loop.